# Ad hoc distribution vs App Store distribution.

Tags: iphone, build, app-store, distribution, adhoc

I want to distribute my app to our few company employees, but when I tried to create an ad hoc distribution profile, it requires the device ID for every single device that I want to install my app on. It is not possible for me to get IDs and I am not sure app store distribution actually submits my app for approval (I am not ready for approval yet).

Is there any simply where I can build my app with distribution profile and then I can share the binary file with our employees so they can install it from iTunes or some other way.

I hope my question is pretty clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the "Enterprise" model of the developer program.  This is specifically designed for companies that want to design vertical integration into their software.  With this program, you are allowed to push/install software to employees without the use of the App Store.

If you are looking just to do basic testing, you best bet is to get the UDIDs of the employees iPhone OS devices that want to test the app.  Then you make the code and distribute with Ad Hoc.

Pain.

Answer (score 2):

Submitting your app to the store would result in it being made available to the general public. Ad hoc distribution is the only solution for the problem you outlined.

The only other alternatives would be to set up each device as a development device (which would be more problematic than just getting the UDID from each device), or jailbreaking all the phones (even more problematic).

There are a few (free) UDID utility iPhone apps available on the store that simplify the process of getting the UDIDs of your end users' devices, if that helps you any.